# htaccess Redirecting or Rewriting to a form results page with variables intact

Tags: .htaccess, form-submit

I am building a website which calls for a page selector on product search results, the page selector currently adds a forward slash and a number (representing the page) to the end of the current URL.

e.g. If I am browsing Washing Machines on "/laundry/Washing-Machines" and I click page 2 on the selector it takes me to "/laundry/Washing-Machines/2" and page 2 loads, this is working fine.

Now, the problem I am having...

I have a form in the sidebar where the user can filter Range Cooker search results by brand, fuel type, size and colour. The form gathers the products from the database that meet the search criteria, and displays the results along side the page selector.

If I leave the form values as default and submit the form I am presented with the results on "/cooking/Range-Cookers/Search?brand=0&type=0&size=0&colour=0" but when I click page 2 on the selector I am taken to "cooking/Range-Cookers/2" which presents me with a 404. If I add "&page=2" to the end of the original URL I am presented with page 2.

Since the page selector is a php include and works fine for every product except the results from my Range Cooker form, I would rather find a solution that leaves the selector php intact.

Is there any way I can add a redirect to .htaccess which would take a link from my page selector e.g. "cooking/Range-Cookers/5" and correctly apply it to the current URL with all form variables intact e.g. "cooking/Range-Cookers/Search?brand=1&type=2&size=0&colour=0&page=5"?

I have experience in HTML, CSS and PHP, but I am new to editing .htaccess and would appreciate any insight into how I can accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with .htaccess, because the information is not available, when the request hits Apache, or .htaccess for that matter.

When you click the link for page 2, the client requests the URL in the associated `href` attribute. It doesn't provide any other information available on the current page. If you want this information transmitted, you must modify the link for page 2 from

```
cooking/Range-Cookers/2
```

to

```
cooking/Range-Cookers/Search?brand=1&type=2&size=0&colour=0&page=2
```

when you deliver the page to the client. Same goes for any other information you need for following pages.